# Python SSL server to provide intermediate CA certificates

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, ca

I am using the Python (2.7) SSL module to write some server code like follows:

`ssock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ca_certs="all-ca.crt", keyfile="server.key", certfile="server.crt", server_side=True, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)`

The 'all-ca.crt' contains the signing CA certificate and the root CA certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (signing CA)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (root CA)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The documentation for the Python SSL module states:

> In general, if you are using SSL3 or TLS1, you don’t need to put the
>   full chain in your “CA certs” file; you only need the root
>   certificates, and the remote peer is supposed to furnish the other
>   certificates necessary to chain from its certificate to a root
>   certificate.

And this is my experience having written SSL servers in C. It doesn't seem to work here though. If I write a client that uses just the root certificate in its wrap_socket() call:

`csock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ca_certs="root-ca.crt", cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)`

then an exception is raised:

> ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:14094418:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca

If instead I pass all-ca.crt to the client ca_certs argument, then everything works as expected, but this is inconvenient at the client side and should not be required.

Is there any way I can tell the server side that it needs to provide the intermediate CA certificates to the client on negotiation?

Comment: Have you tried to bundle your server cert and its chain into `server.crt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the server side, the `ca_certs` option is used to verify client's certificate. (If `CERT_REQUIRED` set to be `True`, the server will ask the client provides its certificate).

In fact, the CA's certificates in `ca_certs` are not sent to clients. The server will just send its own certificate to clients. But you can put all intermediate certificates and your server's certificate into your `server.crt.` For example, using

`cat server.crt intermediate-ca.crt root-ca.crt > server-chain.crt`

to produce the chain.

Comment: "*The server will just send its own certificate to clients. This behavior is according to TLS protocol.*" Not really, the TLS protocol allows for a certificate chain to be sent.

Comment: @Bruno: As a matter of fact, the TLS protocol _requires_ the complete chaing to be sent. To quote [RFC 5246](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.2): "certificate_list  - This is a sequence (chain) of certificates.  The sender's certificate MUST come first in the list.  Each following certificate MUST directly certify the one preceding it." The root certificate is optional, all other intermediates are not. Also see [this similar question on security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57535/why-do-i-need-to-install-the-startcom-intermediate-certificate).